# Visualforce and VPN

Tags: salesforce, vpn, apex-code, visualforce

I'm looking to integrate my Salesforce implementation with an external database. I know that in most circumstances I would use Visualforce with an Apex controller/extension to access the data, however the external database will require a VPN connection. Since Visualforce and any controllers or extensions are processed server-side, is there any way to do this through a VPN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution that occurs to me would be to expose the data via a web service and then write an Apex webservice class to call the data. I've done this several times when data was behind a firewall.

For more complex integrations, where you actually wanted to store the external data in Salesforce with more complex logic it could be useful to use an integration tool like [Jitterbit](http://www.jitterbit.com/) or [Cast Iron](http://www.castiron.com/) to do this for you.